# How do you link two elements together when they have the same name in xslt?

Tags: xslt

I have these trees, one with this structure /cars/car and the second /maker/cars/car. The first one has a reference to the id of the second list of cars.

```
<xsl:template match="t:cars/t:car">
<tr>
    <td>
        <xsl:if test="position()=1">
            <b><xsl:value-of select="../@name"/><xsl:text> </xsl:text></b>
        </xsl:if>


    </td>
</tr>
```

I have this, it was filled in with a for loop I learn after a bit that I could't do it.

This is what it was before:

```
<xsl:template match="t:cars/t:car">
<tr>
    <td>
        <xsl:if test="position()=1">
            <b><xsl:value-of select="../@name"/><xsl:text> </xsl:text></b>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:for-each select="/t:root/t:maker/t:car">
            <xsl:if test="t:root/t:maker/@id = @ref">
                <xsl:value-of select="@title"/>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>

    </td>
</tr>
```

sample:

```
auto>
<maker type="toyota">
    <car name="prius" id="1"/>
</maker>

<cars name="My Collection">
    <car ref="1" />
</cars>
```

Comment: Sample input and required output xml would make it much easier to understand your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This simple transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:key name="kCarById" match="maker/car" use="@id"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
  <table>
   <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </table>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="cars/car">
    <tr>
        <td>
          <b>
           <xsl:value-of select="key('kCarById', @ref)/@name"/>
           </b>
        </td>
    </tr>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on this XML document** (the provided one, just extended a little):

```
<auto>
    <maker type="toyota">
        <car name="prius" id="1"/>
    </maker>
    <maker type="honda">
        <car name="accord" id="2"/>
    </maker>
    <maker type="benz">
        <car name="mercedes" id="3"/>
    </maker>

    <cars name="My Collection">
        <car ref="2" />
        <car ref="3" />
    </cars>
</auto>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td>
         <b>accord</b>
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>
         <b>mercedes</b>
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

**Explanation**: Appropriate use of **[keys](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#key)**.